# Error writing to file fs stream NodeJS

Tags: node.js, csv, fs, csv-write-stream

### Objective

Write a very large array to a file using [csv-write-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-write-stream) and fs stream.

### Background

I have a small app that writes a huge array of data (thousands of entries) to a CSV file. To achieve this I use the aforementioned library, which is nothing more than a mask (a convenience) for the fs stream. However, the application crashes during runtime and I don't know why.

### Error

The file is created and the stream starts writing to it, but then during the execution I always have the same error:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:166:12)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:211:5)
    at ondata (_stream_readable.js:536:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:368:10)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:751:26)
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:609:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:166:7)
```

### Code

I know this error is related with this piece of code:

```
let writer = csvWriter({
    headers: ['country', 'postalCode']
});
let fsStream = fs.createWriteStream('output.csv');
writer.pipe(fsStream);

//very big array !
currCountryCodes = [{country: 'A', postalCode: 0}, {country: 'B', postalCode: 1 }];

for (let j = 0; j < currCountryCodes.length; j++) {
    writer.write(currCountryCodes[j]);
}

writer.end(function() {
  fsStream.end(function() {
    console.log('=== CSV written successfully, stopping application ===');
    process.exit();
  });
});
```

Most specifically to the execution of:

```
fsStream.end(function() {
        console.log('=== CSV written successfully, stopping application ===');
        process.exit();
      });
```

But I can't understand why it happens. Somehow, it only happens when the array I am writing has thousands of lines, if I only have a dozen or so, it runs perfectly fine.

### Question

From reading the error I get the impression that I am still writing to the file after I closed the stream, but that can't be happening because those functions only run when everything is flushed to the file (right?)

- What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you (understandably) assume that when the callback for `writer.end()` gets called, no data will be written to `fsStream` anymore, which is not the case (as the error suggests).

`writer` is a [duplex stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_duplex), which means it's both readable and writable. By calling the [`.end()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_end_chunk_encoding_callback) method, you're telling it that you won't be writing to it anymore. However, that doesn't mean that it still won't be readable.

When you subsequently end `fsStream`, there can still be unflushed data in some buffer that will get piped to `fsStream`, yielding the error.

You can solve this by listening for the [`end`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) event on `writer`, which is the readable equivalent of signaling that there's no data left to be read anymore:

```
writer.end(function() {
  writer.on('end', function() {
    fsStream.end(function() {
      console.log('=== CSV written successfully, stopping application ===');
      process.exit();
    });
  });
});
```

**EDIT**: I think that when `writer.end()` gets called, `fsStream` will automatically be ended as well (so `fsStream.end()` is superfluous, and its callback may not get called because the `finish` event has already been emitted).

You can listen to the `finish` event on `fsStream` if you want to make sure that all data has been flushed to the output file:

```
writer.end(function() {
  fsStream.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('=== CSV written successfully, stopping application ===');
    process.exit();
  });
});
```

Or even:

```
fsStream.on('finish', function() {
  console.log('=== CSV written successfully, stopping application ===');
  process.exit();
});

writer.end();
```

Comment: While the error no longer appears with your suggestion, the final message `'=== CSV written successfully, stopping application ==='` no longer appears and the app no longer terminates :S Perhaps now I don't need to watch for the fsStream event ?

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix see my edit. I think that because of the `.pipe()`, you don't need to end `fsStream`.